# How to connect to DB2 i and z os systems using ODBC in AWS docker image

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker

Connect to DB2 Z and i os systems using ODBC in AWS:

I have tried connecting DB2 using JDBC driver in AWS Glue but Architect suggest use only python code which support only ODBC connection.

---

1. we cannot use the same version of the ibm_db for i and z platform at the same time, let’s use ODBC instead for both, i and z series
2. For I Series we have to install completely different driver - IBM i Access - Client Solutions Linux package.
3. We need to build different Docker image:
   a.   Install unixODBC
   b.   Install IBM i Access ODBC
   c.   Install 11.1 version of the IBM ODBC and CLI driver
   d.   Install pyODBC

Comment: @Bhargav Rao - Was the issue resolved? If Yes, could you share your docker file?